# X9SCL-F and Celeron G470 compatibility

Tags: intel, supermicro

Just wanted to ask if somebody has experience with the combination of X9SCL-F and Celeron G470.

I wanted to buy it, unfortunately a seller hasn't tested this combination, so he didn't want to sell it, even though Celeron is listed in the supported cpu list: http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C202_C204/X9SCL-F.cfm

The server is going to be backup server => goal is low power consumption and low price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the communication with supermicro support. They haven't tested that as well. So they don't recommend it.

This MB supports only celerons:

- G440
- G530
- G530T
- G540
- G540T
- G550
- G620
- G620T
- G630
- G630T
- G640
- G640T
- G840
- G850
- G860
- G860T
- G870